# Captcha loading problem in popup

Tags: asp.net, jquery, captcha

I am using `jquery.load()` to load a page on click of a button.
The page that will be loaded contains a captcha.
When that page is getting loaded due to the captcha it is making the page to reload again and it is not showing anything.
If i am removing the captcha from the load page it is working fine.
I am using ASP.NET.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the captcha perform a `window.location` redirect?

Comment: What framework/library are you using for the captcha? Can you add an ASPX code example?

Comment: Need to provide more informations here about the captcha, and the javascript that you use.

Comment: I have written $('div#tafContent').load('Taf.aspx'); to load the aspx page.

And in the aspx page i have used the captcha which somehow looks like this 
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="reCaptcha" runat="server" Theme="clean"
PublicKey='<%$ AppSettings:PubKey %>' 
PrivateKey='<%$ AppSettings:PriKey %>' />

Answer (score 0):

Use the reCaptcha code for ajax loading: [found here](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX) .